# SQL Connection Issue With Windows 2008+SQL 208

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-c++

I have been working on an application(which was developed on VC++).
by using this application, i have to connect to SQL via ODBC. We have our own datasource, username and password.

This application worked well(i mean SQL connection) is alright with Windows 2003+SQL 2008 OS.
But the same is not working with Windows 2008+SQL 2008.

I suspect few of the SQL APIs/ODBC APIs got changed.

Below is the sample code. Could you please let me know what was wrong in Windows 2008+SQL 2008 environment.

=============================================================

```
BOOL ODBWithTimeout(char *DbSource, char *UserName, char *Password, char *DbName, int sec)
{
RETCODE rc;
HSTMT hstmt;
char        szBuffer[MAX_QUERY_LENGTH];
SQLHANDLE EnvHandle;

        rc = SQLAllocEnv(&henv);

        if (rc==SQL_ERROR)
        {

           return FALSE;
        }
        rc = SQLAllocConnect(henv, &hdbc);

        if (rc==SQL_SUCCESS || rc == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO);
        else 
        {
            SQLFreeEnv(henv);
//          return DbErrorHandler(NULL,"SQLSetConnectOption");  
            return FALSE;
        }
        rc=SQLSetConnectOption(hdbc,SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT,sec);
        if (rc==SQL_SUCCESS || rc == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        ;
        else 
        {
            SQLFreeConnect(hdbc);
            SQLFreeEnv(henv);
//          return DbErrorHandler(NULL,"SQLSetConnectOption");  

            return FALSE;
        }
        rc=SQLSetConnectOption(hdbc,SQL_AUTOCOMMIT,SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF);
        if (rc==SQL_SUCCESS || rc == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        ;
        else
        {
            SQLFreeConnect(hdbc);
            SQLFreeEnv(henv);
//          return DbErrorHandler(NULL,"SQLSetConnectOption");  

            return FALSE;
        }
        rc=SQLSetConnectOption(hdbc, SQL_PACKET_SIZE, 10240);
        rc=SQLConnect(hdbc,DbSource,SQL_NTS,UserName,SQL_NTS,Password,SQL_NTS);     

        if (rc==SQL_SUCCESS || rc == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        {

                   rc = SQLAllocStmt(hdbc, &hstmt);
                   if ((rc == SQL_SUCCESS) || (rc == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
                   {
                        strcpy(szBuffer, "SET ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON OFF");
                        rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (UCHAR*)szBuffer, SQL_NTS);
                        SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_DROP);
                    }

        //turn off SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
        //
                    rc = SQLAllocStmt(hdbc, &hstmt);
                    if ((rc == SQL_SUCCESS) || (rc == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
                    {
                        strcpy(szBuffer, "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF");
                        rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, (UCHAR*)szBuffer, SQL_NTS);
                        SQLFreeStmt(hstmt, SQL_DROP);
                    }


                    SQLAllocStmt(hdbc,&hstmt);
                    wsprintf(usedb,"use %s",DbName);
                    rc=SQLExecDirect(hstmt,usedb,SQL_NTS);
                    if (rc==SQL_SUCCESS || rc == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
                    {
                        rc=SQLTransact(henv,hdbc,SQL_COMMIT);                            
                    }
//                  else return DbErrorHandler(hstmt,"OpenDatabase");   
                    else 
                    {

                        return FALSE;
                    }

        } 
        else 
        {
            SQLFreeConnect(hdbc);
            SQLFreeEnv(henv);
//          return DbErrorHandler(NULL,"OpenDatabase"); 

            return FALSE;
        }


return TRUE;    


}
```

=============================================================

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Jag

====================
My Application is unable to establish connection with SQL in this particular environment : Windows 2008 + SQL 2008

Comment: What exactly isn't working? [Improve your question please.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27940088/edit).

Comment: My Application is unable to establish connection with SQL in this particular environment : Windows 2008 + SQL 2008

Comment: Are there any specific error messages you can provide, or does it fail silently?

Comment: there are no specific error messages. The above function returns as FALSE at:
      rc = SQLAllocConnect(henv, &hdbc);
      if (rc==SQL_SUCCESS || rc == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO);
        else 
        {
            SQLFreeEnv(henv);
//          return DbErrorHandler(NULL,"SQLSetConnectOption");  
            return FALSE;
        }

Comment: IIRC there are methods to get the last error in more detail. Also the actual value of `rc` could contain more information.

Comment: Seems, the SQL APIs got changed with newer ODBC. I am suspecting that could be the reason for failure in establishing connection with SQL. But I cant find any sample code with the new APIs.

Comment: Hello.. Can any one help me here.. I had analyzed more and observed SQLExecDirect() is hanging. Could you help with the reason for hanging of SQLExecDirect

Thanks,